# Regular expression to match all commas outside double and single quotes

Tags: regex, abap

I am trying to match commas outside double quotes(") using the following Regular expression

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

for commas outside single quotes(')

```
,(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

My aim is to ignore commas either inside double quotes or inside single quote using single regular expression.

e.g.

"mahe,ndra"**,** "Gulla" **,** 40 **,** 'te,st'**,** 23

Could you please let me know, How can I handle this.

I will be grateful for your help

Mahendra

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38330923/3832970).

Comment: Hi vwegert, Thanks for your comment. I believe my requirement is  different. I need replace all commas ignoring commas either in single or double quotes. By using above mentioned regular expression I am to ignore either commas in single quote or double quotes  and not both at a time.

Comment: Could you please provide more large testing text maybe 5 - 10 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
,(?=(?:(?:[^"']*"[^"']*")|(?:[^'"]*'[^'"]*'))*[^"']*$)
```

It will match commas outside single and double quotes as provided examples, but will fail if the input have odd number of quotes.

Comment: Hi Koala, Thank you very much, your solution is working well for me

Answer (score 2):

Some alternative workaround is here

```
,(?=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\d+)(?:\s*,|\n))
```

My method emphasizes on validating such a pattern like `,"[^"]*",`, `,'[^']*',` or `,\d+,`. The trick here is if starting point of the matching is correct then the rest of the matching till the end of the line will also be correct.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zD5sU0/1)

Comment: Hi fronthem, Thank you very much your help. Your solutions is also worked well for me